Determine the transfer function for the Butterworth bandpass filter? (At the Transfer Function Factoring and Sp Substitution stage)
The Parameter
$$a_{pass} = - 1dB$$
$$a_{stop} = - 20dB$$
$$f_{pass1} = 10kHz$$
$$f_{pass2} = 30kHz$$
$$f_{stop1} = 5kHz$$
$$f_{stop2} = 60kHz$$
A. Approximate Low Pass Filter

Filter Ordo
$$n_B = 4.29$$
$$n_B = 5 $$

Magnitude Response
$$\epsilon = 0.51$$

Radius
$$R = 1,144$$

Angles
$$m = 1$$



While m = 0
$$\theta_0 = 108°$$

While m = 1
$$\theta_1 = 144°$$



Find $$\sigma_m$$ Value and $$\omega_m$$ value


While m = 0

$$\sigma_0 = -0.354 $$
$$\omega_0 = 1.089 $$

While m = 1

$$\sigma_1 = -0.926 $$
$$\omega_1 = 0.673 $$
$$\sigma R = - 1.144$$

Find Value B1m and B2m

$$B_{1,0} = 0.708$$
$$B_{1,1} = 1.852 $$
$$B_{2,0} = 1.311 $$
$$B_{2,1} = 1.310 $$

Low Pass Filter Aproximation Transfer Function

$$H_{B,5}(S) = \frac{1.144}{S} \frac{(1.311)(1.310)}{(S^2 + 0.708S + 1.311)(S^2 +  1.852 + 1.310)}$$
B. Unnormalized Butterworth Band Pass Filter

$$ \Omega_{rP} $$

$$ \Omega_{rP} = 2.75$$

$$ \omega_0 $$

$$ \omega_0 = 108.827,96 rad/s$$

$$BW$$

$$BW = 125.663,71 rad/s$$

$$Sp = \frac{s^2+108.827,96}{125.663,71s}$$

Factoring Transfer Function and Subtitute S.


I'm still confused about the step of factoring the transfer function and substituting specific values to determine the transfer function of a Butterworth bandpass filter. Can someone help me?

How did you decide the order was 4.29?

I have calculated it with the existing formula.

What existing formula?

nb = log[10^-0.1astop2 - 1)/ (10^-0.1apass2 - 1) / 2 log (wstop/wpass)

Please don't add "HELP" to your question titles. Everybody is here for help – putting it in the title is unnecessary and just makes people less likely to read it :)

Alright, im sorry @MarcusMüller

@SKevinAR18 Your fractional bandwidth (there are at least two definitions for the term, so I'll define mine here as $\frac{f_{\text{HI}}-f{\text{LO}}}{\sqrt{f{\text{HI}},\cdot , f{_\text{LO}}}}$) is $\frac12\sqrt{2}$. This is right at the cusp of where I would decide on using a combination of separately designed low-pass and a high-pass filters or where instead I could go for a higher-order filter that combines everything. You seem, though, to be about factoring so this would push me towards separately designed low-pass and a high-pass filters. But you need to write more, I fear.

@SKevinAR18 (And yes, I still understand this is Butterworth and not some other filter.)

@periblepsis Yeah, this is Butterworth. I still don't understand how to factor it. Because in the book 'Practical Analog and Digital Filter Design (Artech House Microwave Library),' there's an example in UNNORMALIZED BANDPASS APPROXIMATION FUNCTIONS. H(s) = 2/(S^2+2S+2) then the factorization is 2/((S+1+j1)(S+1-j1)). And my transfer function looks a little bit complicated. Or do I just need to factor it like normal and add +j1/-j1. This imaginary j makes me confused.

@SKevinAR18 You need to get on board with complex analysis. For example, multiplication in complex number systems involves both rotation and scaling. In real number systems, it's just scaling. No rotation included. Once you get on board with the extra behavior with complex multiplication, stuff gets easier to visualize. I mentioned a demarcation where you might use a low-pass and a high pass to create a bandpass. But conversely you may need to combine both in one system. Any way you can write more about what you know and don't know?

@periblepsis Yeah, that's correct. I have to understand complex analysis.  Maybe I will search for more references about this because i think there is a lack of people doing this. I will inform you if i get more information.

@SKevinAR18 Okay. Let me know. This isn't rocket science, luckily. But there is a change of viewpoint in understanding what multiplication means, in complex number systems vs real number systems. Real number multiplication is just simple scaling. Complex number multiplication is both rotation plus scaling. So get your head around that. 3Blue1Brown (Grant Sanderson) provides youtube videos that may help a lot here.

@SKevinAR18 I will help out if I see that what I write is in the right direction for you. So keep that in mind. But I need to understand better what to write before I take the time. Just FYI.
